# C++: How would one implement their own String class?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to re-learn C++ and was wondering if anyone could help me out here. I'm trying to implement my own String class to see if I can remember things, but I'm stuck on the constructor.

I have my header file and want to have a constructor as so:

**Header File (MyFiles\String.h):**

```
#ifndef STRING_
#define STRING_

using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class String
{
  private:

    static const unsigned int MAX = 32;    // Capacity of string

    char Mem[MAX];    // Memory to hold characters in string
    unsigned Len;     // Number of characters in string

  public:

    // Construct empty string
    //
    String()
    {
      Len = 0;
    }

    // Reset string to empty
    //
    void reset()
    {
      Len = 0;
    }

    // Return status information
    //
    bool empty() const
    {
      return Len == 0;
    }

    unsigned length() const
    {
      return Len;
    }

    // Return reference to element I
    //
    char& operator[]( unsigned I )
    {
      return Mem[I];
    }

    // Return constant reference to element I
    //
    const char& operator[]( unsigned I ) const
    {
      return Mem[I];
    }

    // Construct string by copying existing string
    //
    String( const String& );

    // Construct string by copying array of characters
    //
    String( const char [] );

    // Copy string to the current string
    //
    String& operator=( const String& );

    // Append string to the current string
    //
    String& operator+=( const String& );
};

// Compare two strings
//
bool operator==( const String&, const String& );
bool operator!=( const String&, const String& );

// Put a string into an output stream
//
ostream& operator<<( ostream&, const String& );

#endif
```

The bit I'm stuck on is this:

```
String::String(const String& str)
{
    //what goes here?
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The world really would be nicer without another string class...

Comment: @Kornel: the point of the exercise is to learn, not to replace std::string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since it's a learning exercise.

I think you want to copy the contents of the other string here since this is a copy constructor.  So you will want to copy across all the member variables.  In your case
the copy constructor is not necessary because you've got a static array.  If you had
dynamic memory (i.e. used new to allocate pointer to Mem) then you'd need this.  However,
to show you how it's done, here you go.

```
String::String(const String& str)
{
    //what goes here?
    assert(str.Len < MAX);  // Hope this doesn't happen.
    memcpy(Mem, str.Mem, str.Len);
    Len = str.Len;
}
```

Comment: I should clarify, there is a default copy constructor defined that by default copies all member variables.  If you have dynamic memory then you need to define a copy constructor.

Comment: +1, this is what I was going to say, although I would emphasise the key point - don't implement a copy ctor or copy assignment operator when the default already does the right thing. There's a possible optimization, that copying just `Len` bytes saves some copying for short strings, but 32 bytes isn't enough that I'd worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the data from `str` to `this`. The length is easy:

```
Len = str.Len; // or, equiv. this->Len= str.Len
```

The data is a little harder. You might use `strcpy` or `memcpy`, or even a for loop.

```
memcpy(Mem, str.Mem, sizeof Mem);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Minor point, That memcpy copies the whole mem array including those beyond Len that are not part of the string but are in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Kornel Kisielewicz: the fewer hand-rolled String classes, the better. But you're only doing this to learn, so fair enough :-). Anyway: your copy constructor needs to copy over the length and the contents of the `Mem` array, and that's it.

(If you were doing this to make something useful rather than as a learning exercise, I'd add: a string class with a fixed maximum string length -- especially one as small as 32 characters -- is a very bad idea indeed. But it's entirely reasonable if you don't feel like dealing with memory allocation and deallocation at the same time as you're trying to remember the even-more-basics...)