# implementing own string class in c++

Tags: c++, string

I know that there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332971/c-how-would-one-implement-their-own-string-class).
However my implementation is a bit different,

```
class String {
    private:
        char* str;
        long int length;
    public:
        String() {
            str = NULL;
            length = 0;
        }
        void input() {
            char c;
            while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
                str = new char[length + 1];
                length++;
                str[length - 1] = c;
            }
            str = new char[length + 1];
            str[length] = '\0';
        }
        long int getLength() {
            return length;
        }
        void display() {
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                cout<<str[i];
        }
        ~String() {
            delete[] str;
            length = 0;
        }
};

int main(void) {
    String s;
    s.input();
    cout<<s.getLength()<<endl;
    s.display();
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

in this code, for some reason, my display function is giving weird results.
Can anyone help me with this function?

Comment: What do you think happens with the ”old” characters when you replace your pointer with a new one?

Comment: Well I experimented on that and surprisingly, they don't get deleted, at least not in windows.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I should use realloc instead?

Comment: Don't use realloc. Copy the old string to the new.

Comment: "implementing own string class in c++" - Don't. Use  an existing one like `std::string`, `QString`, `gstring`, `SFString` or similar. They are all *very* likely to be *much better* than what you can implement on your own.

Comment: `str = new char[length + 1]` and `str = new char[length + 1]` after each other. What happens with the pointer in the second assignment? What happens with the memory you first allocate? It's like doing `int a = 5; a = 10;` and then wondering why `a` is not equal to `5` anymore.

Comment: Your allocation in while loop in `input()` is definitely wrong. You leak memory and don't copy the previous string. Also you probably should not increase the allocated size by 1 each time. `new`  and `delete` are costly operations.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I want to learn the logic. I know that kernighan's implementation is waaay better. ... has to be. But if I keep using ready-made things, when will I learn logic? I am not as experienced as you. When I actually have to use, I will definitely use inbuilt functionalities provided as you suggested :)

Comment: @drescherjm I want to save as much space as I can. If that were the case, I would definitely have preferred char arrays

Comment: @kesarling If you are going to write a container that manages a resource (in this case memory owned by a raw pointer) then you certainly need to apply the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Otherwise trying to move, copy or destroy your object will be problematic.

Comment: Yes you have to implement the rule of 3 in your case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188132/discussion-on-question-by-kesarling-implementing-own-string-class-in-c). If you have advice, *post an answer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void appendChar(char c) {
    if (length + 2 >= capacity) { // one for append and one for null byte
        capacity += 128;
        char *newPtr = new char[capacity];
        if (length > 0) {
            strcpy(newPtr, str);
        }
        if (str != NULL) {
            delete [] str;
        }
        str = newPtr;
    }
    str[length++] = c; // append the character
    str[length] = 0; // add a null byte so it's zero terminated
}
```

Then call this method from your read method instead of doing the extra stuff yourself.

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    appendChar(c);
}
```

You'll notice I made use of a new class field -- capacity.

Comment: You may want to mention the initialization of capacity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the input method is not doing what you expect it to do, this:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
                str = new char[length + 1];
```

Will create a new char[] for every char input, so when displaying the string, you get random garbage.

Additionally, after the loop you also do this:

```
}
            str = new char[length + 1];
```

Again creating a new array of char pointers, but never actually taking the contents of the previous one.

To solve this, using your method of getting input, i would do something like set an initial size of the char[] to be some arbitrary number (e.g. 8) and only allocating more memory once you read more than 8 chars. afterwards, you can allocate twice this size, copy the contents of the previous char[] and continue reading using getchar().

Hope this helps

Comment: @kesarling For this allocation you may want to look at how the linked example that you gave handles capacity. However instead of making the capacity a fixed compile time constant (the linked example does that) you can allow it to expand. When it expands you need to reallocate and copy the previously allocated string.

Comment: But one thing I don't get is, why is realloc not compatible with new and delete?
I mean reallocating memory by copying it to some other chunk will take twice the size (of course temporarily till I delete the old chunk), whereas realloc will simply expand that size. I mean isn't that how realloc works? or does it do the same thing what I have to do using new and delete just automatically?